# image encrypt/decrypt between php and Android

Tags: imagemagick

I want to encrypt an image using PHP and decrypt it in an Android app. I found someone suggest to use MCrypt. However, I noticed that ImageMagick, which I use to convert pdf into jpg, seemed to have ability for encryption. Can I use ImageMagick to encrypt the jpg at the server side and decrypt it using JAVA? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation

"ImageMagick only scrambles the image pixels. The image metadata remains untouched and readable by anyone with access to the image file.
ImageMagick uses the AES cipher in Counter mode. We use the the first half of your passphrase to derive the nonce. The second half is the cipher key."

To decrypt the image on the client side, you would have to keep the image header as is and decrypt the remainder of the file using the password with which it was encrypted with. That will require custom coding with knowledge of the image format internals. You will also have to find out how the nonce is derived from the passphrase.

You can alternatively use a SSL connection between the client and server or use any cryptographic scheme available in both PHP and Java either with symetric key or public key encryption as per your requirements.